Which GAE SDK first supported JDK 8?
Which is the first version of the (legacy) App Engine Java SDK that supports Java 8 and doesn't throw:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl can not access a member of class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.$Proxy0 with modifiers "public"
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:413)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl.cast(ClearCast.java:383)

Which of the 1.x.x versions first supported JDK 8? I'm looking for the version number.

v1.9.54 first supported Java 8 in beta but with some limitations
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/release-notes#June_28_2017
v1.9.57 was the first release with stable Java 8 support
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/release-notes#September_25_2017
